# z-index not working with my background link

Tags: html, css

I pass my background image through a hyperlink in order to link the background image it work but when i added z-index:-1; it did not work anymore below is my code help me with it thanks.

```
.bg {
    position: fixed;
    background:url(../bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    width:1365px;
    height:665px;
    z-index:-1;
}

<a href="home.html" class="bg">Ad</a>
```

Comment: It works perfectly when I try your code (http://jsfiddle.net/xfwcsjrk/) so it is probably giving some conflicts with other css. Can you share your entire code in a jsfiddle please?

Comment: noticed sb voted your question down,I voted your question up. may i know what's the motivation made you add z-index: value to -1? when you're already done.

Comment: i add Z index -1; because the background image is covering my web page so i have to order it to the back with Z index -1; immediately i did that the link on the background image did not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Z index -1 means that you hide it behind any other element in that location, so if your code includes any elements with a higher z-index, you won't be able to see your image, please link the rest of the code for more info.

Comment: i want the background image to go back cos is covering my web page so i have to order it to the back with Z index -1; immediately i did that the link on the background image did not work. I want the link to work with it

Comment: How is the link supposed to work when there is something on top of it?